# Organizing a comments table: How to justify the choice?

Tags: database-design, schema, rdbms, scalability

**Business domain description**

Some of the entity types of interest with respect to the relevant business domain are *money*, *user* and *progress*.

The *users* may need to post *comments* about *money* and *progress*.

In the future, maybe there will be more entity types related to *comment*, not only *money* and *progress*.

**My considerations**

I have three solutions:

1. One `comments` table for all, keeps the "commented entity id" and the "type of entity" of relevance.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE comment (
       user_id …, -- the identifier of who leaves comment
       text …, -- text of the comment
       created_at …, -- tells when comment has been left
       subject_type …, -- 'money' or 'progress'
       subject_id … -- identifier from 'money' or 'progress', depends on the 'subject_type' value
   );
   ```
2. One `comment` table for all. Each table retains a foreign key in the `comment_id` column. The table has a "complex" primary key `(id, created_at)`, and the `id` values are not unique.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE comment (
       id…, -- not unique
       created_at…, -- indicates when the comment was left  
       user_id…, -- identifier of who leaves comment
       text…, -- the text of the comment
       CONSTRAINT comment_pk PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at) -- "complex" primary key
   );
   ```

   When I need to get all *comments* associated with a given entity instance, I obtain them by means of an operation like `SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id = comment_id`.
3. Separate tables, e.g. `comment_money`, `comment_job`, ... All the tables will look the same:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE comment_<entityName> (
       id…,
       entity_id…, -- id of the commented entity
       user_id…, -- who leaves comment
       text…, -- text of the comment
       create_at… -- when the comment was left  
   );
   ```

I prefer the third variant despite the fact that I have to create more tables, because the logic will be really simple and this approach is easy to manage and support.

**Question**

I will pass the model of database (see "business domain description") to a teacher and I'm not sure how to justify my choice. I think that the teacher can say that my approach is bad because all my tables have the same columns and structure.

- What would be good arguments?
- Maybe there are more solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but more of a set of reflections. However it is to long for a comment so I'll add it as an answer anyhow. These are the base tables if I get it right:

```
CREATE TABLE USER
( USER_ID ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ... );

CREATE TABLE MONEY
( MONEY_ID ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ... );

CREATE TABLE PROGRESS
( PROGRESS_ID ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ... );
```

Since I don't know your business I just invented some identifier as a primary key. It may very well be a composite key, but for simplicity I do it like this.

### Alternative 1:

```
CREATE TABLE comment 
( user_id ... not null references USER (user_id)
, text ...
, created_at ...
, subject_type ... -- 'money' or 'progress'
, subject_id ... -- identifier from 'money' or 'progress'
);
```

In all essential this is a union type for comments on either MONEY or PROGRESS. It is a construction that does not really fit well in a relational world. One major drawback is that it will not be possible to implement referential integrity (foreign key). I'm not sure what the primary key would be here.

### Alternative 2:

I'm not sure I understand what you are saying here. Is MONEY dependent of the COMMENT? I.e.

```
CREATE TABLE comment (
    id…, -- not unique
    created_at ... not null
    user_id… not null references USER (user_id)
    text ... not null
    CONSTRAINT comment_pk PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at)
);

ALTER TABLE MONEY ADD CONSTRAINT ...
    FOREIGN KEY (MONEY_ID, created_at) -- add created_at in MONEY
    REFERENCES COMMENT (id, created_at);
```

and similar for PROGRESS. If this is what you mean then the COMMENT will have to exist before MONEY or PROGRESS and this seems counter intuitive to me.

### Alternative 3

I would probably change the name to:

```
CREATE TABLE MONEY_COMMENT
( MONEY_ID ... REFERENCES MONEY (MONEY_ID)
, USER_ID ... REFERENCES USER (USER_ID)
, CREATED_AT ...
, ...
,    PRIMARY KEY (MONEY_ID, USER_ID, CREATED_AT) );
```

and a similar table PROGRESS_COMMENT. I share your thoughts that this is the most elegant solution. If you are interested in all COMMENTS by a USER you can create a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW COMMENTS AS 
    SELECT 'money' as COMMENT_TYPE
         , MONEY_ID AS COMMENT_ID
         , USER_ID
         , CREATED_AT 
         , ...
    FROM MONEY_COMMENT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'progress' as COMMENT_TYPE
         , PROGRESS_ID AS COMMENT_ID
         , USER_ID
         , CREATED_AT 
         , ...
    FROM PROGRESS_COMMENT
```

Comment: I've used third, because of Single responsibility (SOLID) :)You are right about second variant, I was think about get rid of `subject_type` and use one table for all comments. I've missed one important moment: in case there are more than one comment for entity - one fk not enough :)